# Write Windows Phone 8 app using Java API?

Tags: java, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am looking to develop a Windows Phone 8 application based on a Java API but I'm not sure how to proceed. The developer of the original java application said he doesn't have enough demand for a WP8 version, so all that's available is the API. Unfortunately, I don't have any experience in interoperability of these two.

How can I call the java functions from WP8? My guess is that I must have a server in the middle to make the connection?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The only way this would work is if you create a web service on top of the Java API (I assume its a library you're referring to).  Then have the WP8 app call the web service.  There should be plenty of pages online showing you how to consume web services from WP